# Is it possible to customize the displayValue color individually in fusioncharts?

Tags: fusioncharts

I am using the 3D Bar chart in FusionCharts. I have displayValues set to display numeric and textual values above the top of the bars.  What I would like to be able to do is set the **color** of individual displayValues differently, for example, if the year-over-year change is positive, color the displayValue for just that bar to green, if it is negative, color it red, etc.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of coloring data plots or data values based on its value. But FusionCharts has an extensive API used to configure Annotations. You can use this API to create texts (data values). Just a rough thought came into my mind.